# Zabbix- Ping check from SNMP monitored host

Tags: router, ping, zabbix, icmp

May be this question is like a dumb but I need help.

Is there any way to ping an IP from a Cisco device specially a router that is monitored through SNMP by zabbix? Have root/admin access to both router and zabbix. I need to ping the WAN Gateway of the router, currently I am checking ICMP from zabbix but if there is any disruption between zabbix and router it triggers but I need to get trigger actually if there is any disruption from the router to it's gateway. Interface down trigger does not help.

​​​​​​​Is there any way to check ICMP from Cisco router and send the data to zabbix and log it?

Or any other way to get continuous ping data from router that is reportable by daily, weekely and day wise.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you would need an external script for that, and it would fail if there is any disruption between Zabbix Server and router. You can't overcome that, but you can put a Zabbix Proxy "near" the router to mitigate it, if the issue is that there are many hops between Zabbix Server and router.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external